# Calling package befor xepersian in class that call xepersian without change class

Tags: geometry, documentclass-writing, xepersian

I want to customize report class, so that the new class loads the packages  and I do not need to call the lot of packages I usually use. So I wrote the class called `SecondReport` like below:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{SecondReport}
              [2016/05/27  v0.2 A Tufte-style document class in XeLaTeX for
               typesetting Persian books]

 \newif\if@NoXepersian
\DeclareOption{NoXepersian}{\@NoXepersiantrue}  

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{report}

\if@NoXepersian
\else
\RequirePackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.15]{XB Niloofar}
\fi
```

When I use this class without the option `NoXepersian`, as in this case:

```
\documentclass[]{SecondReport}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
یک متن آزمایشی
\end{document}
```

I do get the error:

> "you have loaded geometry after bidi ..."

I have to call `geometry` before `xepersian` but I dont want to change the class.

If I use the `NoXeprsian` option, it inactivates loading of the `xepersian`.  This code is working without an error:

```
\documentclass[NoXepersian]{SecondReport}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
یک متن آزمایشی
\end{document}
```

I would like to know, how to call `geometry` before `xepersian` without any change in my class.

Comment: Hossein, I am afraid, but I think, you'll have to adapt your newly written class.  If you decide, to change the class, that is, if you let your class load the babel package, you can of course order, to load `babel` before `xepersian`.  Problem could be solved very easily that way.

Comment: Any news to report here?